# constexpr conversion of hex chars to std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, type-conversion

I have a number of strings like this:

```
"343536"_hex
```

that I would like to convert into their corresponding byte strings.  I am using C++11and have defined a user-defined string literals to convert these into hex strings. However, the conversion I currently have cannot be evaluated as a `constexpr` which is what I'm seeking.  In particular I would like to use something like this, but as a `constexpr`:

```
std::string operator "" _hex(const char *s, std::size_t slen )
{
    std::string str;
    str.reserve(slen);
    char ch[3];
    unsigned long num;
    ch[2] = '\0';

    for ( ; slen; slen -= 2, s += 2) {
        ch[0] = s[0];
        ch[1] = s[1];
        num = strtoul(ch, NULL, 16);
        str.push_back(num);
    }
    return str;
}
```

### Test driver

```
int main()
{
    std::string src{"653467740035"_hex};
    for (const auto &ch : src)
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') 
                  << (unsigned)ch << '\n';
}
```

### Sample output

```
65
34
67
74
00
35
```

### The question

To be very, very clear about what I'm asking, it's this:
**How can I write a C++11 string literal conversion of this type that can be evaluated at compile time as a `constexpr`?**

Comment: `This doesn't quite work` is a bit of an understatement, most of the types in your `constexpr` function aren't literal types, they cannot be used at compile time.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear.  For the record, yes, I am aware that this conversion won't work as a `constexpr` -- **that is the essence of the question**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are trying to do, you will need to have some compile-time `string` class that is compatible with `constexpr`. There isn't such a standard thing though. I can see some things that approach it:

- [`boost::mpl::string`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/string.html), but the interface is not really pretty.
- [`boost::log::string_literal`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/boost/log/utility/string_literal.hpp), which has the interface you want but lacks the `constexpr` support.
- [`std::string_literal`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4121.pdf), which is exactly what you are looking for, but which isn't implemented. It can probably be implementable in C++11 though if you have some free time.

In order to simplify all of this, let's use an overly simplified `string_literal` class. Note that some of the classes described above have a trailing `\0` to be closer to `std::string`, but we won't bother to add one.

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct string_literal
{
    char data[N];
};
```

We will also provide `operator+` for concatenation. It would take some time to explain how it works and it's not really relevant for the question. Let's say that it is just some template wizardry ([`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) is a C++14 utility but can be implemented in C++11):

```
template<std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2, std::size_t... Ind1, std::size_t... Ind2>
constexpr auto concatenate(string_literal<N1> lhs, string_literal<N2> rhs,
                   std::index_sequence<Ind1...>, std::index_sequence<Ind2...>)
    -> string_literal<N1+N2>
{
    return { lhs.data[Ind1]... , rhs.data[Ind2]... };
}

template<std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
constexpr auto operator+(string_literal<N1> lhs, string_literal<N2> rhs)
    -> string_literal<N1+N2>
{
    using Indices1 = std::make_index_sequence<N1>;
    using Indices2 = std::make_index_sequence<N2>;
    return concatenate(lhs, rhs, Indices1{}, Indices2{});
}
```

You can use the template user-defined literal (with `char...`) to get rid of the string literal and have a prettier literal (`1234_hex` instead of `"1234"_hex`):

```
template<char... Chars>
auto operator "" _hex()
    -> string_literal<sizeof...(Chars)/2>
{
    return process<Chars...>();
}
```

Now, all you need is a function that can process your characters by pairs. A generic one and an overload for the "finish" condition. Note that the `enable_if_t` is needed to avoid ambiguous function calls (that's C++14, but you can replace it by `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` in C++11). The "real" work of converting the characters to the equivalent numbers is done in the `process` overload that only takes two template arguments.

```
template<char C1, char C2>
constexpr auto process()
    -> string_literal<1>
{
    return { 16 * (C1 - '0') + (C2 - '0') };
}

template<char C1, char C2, char... Rest,
         typename = std::enable_if_t< (sizeof...(Rest) > 0), void >>
constexpr auto process()
    -> string_literal<sizeof...(Rest)/2 + 1>
{
    return process<C1, C2>() + process<Rest...>();
}
```

You could add many more checks to ensure that there is always an even number of characters or to ensure that there aren't any bad characters. The code I provided uses some features from the C++14 standard library, but I made sure to only use features that can be easily reimplemented in C++11 if needed. Note that you could probably write a more human-readable program with C++14 thanks to the relaxed restrictions on `constexpr` functions.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31536bd0880a1793) is a working C++14 example with all the aforementioned functions and classes. I made sure that your test program still works (I just replaced `scr` by `scr.data` in the loop since we use an edulcorated `string_literal` class).